# python pandas как получить индекс строки содержащей минимальное значение в столбце

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть такой dataframe:  df

| id | datetime | high | close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-05-02 | 1.0542 | 1.46579 |
| 2 | 2022-05-03 | 1.04187 | 1.42004 |

```
minimum_close = df.close.min()
```

Как можно получить индекс строки или значение даты для строки, содержащей минимальное значение
в столбце 'close' ???

Comment: отсортировать по `close` и взять значение из первой строки

Comment: Воспользуйтесь методом `argmin` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.argmin.html

Comment: Спасибо )   метод argmin - помог !!!